# How best to update row where composite primary key values change

Tags: sql, database, db2, primary-key, composite-primary-key

We have numerous tables where we have composite keys with MULTIPLE entries. In some cases as many as SIX values that make up the primary key for a table that is not super large, maybe a few thousand entries, and is not accessed very heavily.

A better solution to this would be to use a primary key that is a single auto-incremented ID field and in order to make sure the combination of the six different fields now used as a primary key are unique you can create an index with a unique constraint. The performance might not be quite so good, but the code complexity would be DRASTICALLY reduced.

I was told that making the primary key so complex is necessary because the primary key is the only clustered index on a table and that this enhances the performance. I can understand how this would help, but is it THAT big of a performance enhancement? It seems to be a premature optimization.

Is it common practice to use composite primary keys? I understand that if you had a very large table, with many thousands of entries, and that was hit constantly, then even a small performance enhancement could be worth adding the complexity I am seeing.

It also seems like having a primary key made up of values that can be updated/changed is just asking for trouble. If other tables are referencing it couldn't that lead to issues?

This would mostly be for adding new tables, since changing the structure of the existing tables could be too drastic a change for them to accept. But I want to know if I am out of line before trying to push back against this practice.

Comment: "...because the primary key is the only clustered index..." -- that would depend on the specific database and also on table-creation parameters. What database are you using?

Comment: "...It seems to be a bit of a premature optimization situation." -- Absolutely. For a 2k-rows table that's non-sense. If you were talking about a highly demanded 2-million row table, maybe. For 2 billions rows, that would be a yes.

Comment: The one in question is DB2. But I think the practice is extended to an MSSQL DB that to which the data gets replicated. But I am not completely sure about that part. Still a bit new.

Comment: "...primary key made up of values that can be updated/changed is just asking for trouble." -- There's nothing theoretically wrong about updating the PK. However, it's design decision that should not be taking lightly. Most of the time the updates are done for the wrong reasons.

Comment: [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284) [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [mre] 
[ask] [Help] Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: @phillipxy This is the kind of response that is increasingly making this site a hostile place to seek answers. It smacks of hostility, elitism and arrogance. Not trying to be hostile here myself, but these links all seem to be attacks on my question rather than an attempt to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Generally using many columns to form a PRIMARY KEY is the worst practice that I found regularly in my databases audits. In fact it was used in the hierarchical database model dating in the 50's... This was dropped due to poor performance !

Database relational model says that the key can be any column or group of columns, but the database experts and practionners have all demonstrates that the best way to have performances in order to ensure the scalability, is to have a key that is only one column, and with a datatype that is :

- the shortest in terms of bytes
- the biggest in terms of values
- with asemantic values
- in a monotonous order

The only way to assume all these considerations is to have a PRIMARY KEY with an auto-increment dataype such as IDENTITY or SEQUENCE.

Every other datatype or ways to do so have some extraoverhead or performs poorly.

In the case of PK with compound columns, the statistics for the optimizer are accurate only for the first column of the key. The statistics of the combination of multiple columns does not exists in any accurate way (except for a complete set of all value of the key in the case of a strict equality and of course this is always equal to 1) and conducts the optimizer to get an average of the global selectivity or worst, compute a correlated cardinality. In both case the execution plan will be of poor quality and sometime catastrophic...

For MS SQL Server clustered indexes are the best choice for PK, only if all the specification I wrote are strictly applied.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @SQLpro. It seems to fit with my limited experience, which is mostly in doing coding in Java and C# for DBs that had already been optimized by a DBA. I wonder if you can speak to any of the same qualities vis-a-vis DB2, since that is the DB I am currently doing the work on. Is it the same, do you know?

Comment: All big RDBMS (IBM DB2, Oracle and MS SQL Server) do quite the same way...